# Python: How to replace substring occurrences with next values from list?

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I have the following string and list:

```
myString = "a:::b:::c:::d ..... "  where ':::' is sort of delimiter
myList = [1,2,3,4.......]
```

I know how to cycle through list values, but how do i replace each occurrence of ':::' with next value in list, such that my final output is as follows:

```
myString = "a1b2c3d ...."
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to cycle through the list values? That would help us know how to assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick & Dirty:

```
myString = "a:::b:::c:::d"
myList = [1,2,3,4]

s = iter(myString.split(":::"))

print(next(s) + "".join(str(y)+x for x,y in zip(s,myList)))
```

prints `a1b2c3d`

Comment: That was fast man! Took you all of 10 minutes i guess :). Only one lingering doubt - i'm receiving multiple myStrings with ':::' as delimiter. When i do a for loop on each iteration of myString, values from myList always start at the first value even though the scope of myList is outside the loop. For e.g.  

Input (for loop on these strings):
a:::b:::c:::d
e:::f:::g:::h

Output
a1b2c3d
e1f2g3h

Instead of:
a1b2c3d
e4f5g6h

Comment: Never mind my scoping was wrong. I corrected it; thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
l = myString.split(":::")    
result = "".join([x + str(y) for (x,y) in zip(l, myList)])
```

Comment: That sets myString to `a1b2c3d4` when it was `a:::b:::c:::d` before.

Comment: In the question, they say the target output should `a1b2c3d` (without the trailing 4), but you're right insofar as the question isn't really well-defined.

Comment: Ohh I just assumed the ... meant the same pattern for the rest of the string.

Comment: Sure, but the question is how it is supposed to end. I base my interpretation on the fact that they asked for replacing `:::` with the next element, which doesn't happen in your case (there's no trailing `:::`). In any case, let's wait to see what OP says; maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.

```
def join_string_and_list( string, list ):
    string = string.split(":::")
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        if string[i] != '' and len(list) > 0:
            string.append("{}{}".format(string.pop(0),list.pop(0)))

    return str("".join(string))

myString = "a:::b:::c:::d:::"  #where ':::' is sort of delimiter
myList = [1,2,3,4]

print(join_string_and_list( myString, myList ))
```